# how to create a job to launch python script on google-BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jobs

I have a problem on google-BigQuery:

1. I wrote a query.
2. I open the shell and I create a *Python* **script** that call the query and save the data in CSV file in a subdir of my home on **BigQuery**, and so far so good.

Now, all the files (.py and .csv) are that directory of BigQuery:
`stefano_giostra@[MY_PROJECT]:~/bb_stkovf_data$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefano_giostra stefano_giostra 2724 Aug  7 01:51 best_answer_on_google-bigquery_90gg_20180807_0151.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefano_giostra stefano_giostra  669 Aug  7 01:51 domande_risposte_2014_2015.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefano_giostra stefano_giostra  155 Aug  7 01:51 python_developer_by_nation_20180807_0151.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefano_giostra stefano_giostra  770 Aug  7 01:51 query.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefano_giostra stefano_giostra 7744 Aug  7 01:50 sg_bb_stkorw_info.py`

1. I wish to see the CSV on the **BigQuery** or **GCP** UI, how can I?
2. I wish also generate a job that simply calls the script, and I don't wish to build ad HTML application only to schedule a call of a query.

In the documentation I haven't seen any yaml file where there is a call of a .py  but only of a .app and in all documentation that I'd read in these days I haven't seen how to do that.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify where are you saving the CSV file and in which UI do you want to see it, please?

Comment: Hi Ruben,   
is it clearer now? ;)

Comment: Looks so clear! But try not to share private stuff like your project/bucket IDs and surname when posting on public forums. I would reedit and use [PROJECT_ID], [BUCKET_NAME] and [USER_ACCOUNT] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answers below:

1. To visualize the CSV in BigQuery you have to first load it in a table [as described here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source). Then you can visualize it as a regular table (using preview or querying for particular fields).
2. I found a way from JMD, who is a Technical Solutions Representative in Google, AKA trustworthy source, in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035014/how-to-schedule-the-shell-script-using-google-cloud-shell). The solution uses a Cron job in a Compute Engine f1-micro instance, which allows you to run the script without modifying it and having to build an 'HTML' application, which you don't want:

> To schedule a script you first have to create a project if you don’t
>   have one. I assume you already have a project so if that’s the case
>   just create the instance that you want for scheduling this script.
>
> To create the new instance:
>
> 1. At the Google Cloud Platform Console click on Products & Services which is the icon with the four bars at the top left hand corner.
> 2. On the menu go to the Compute section and hover on Compute Engine and then click on VM Instances.
> 3. Go to the menu bar above the instance section and there you will see a Create Instance button. Click it and fill in the configuration
>      values that you want your new instance to have. The values that you
>      select will determine your VM instance features. You can choose, among
>      other values, the name, zone and machine type for your new instance.
> 4. In the Machine type section click the drop-down menu tab to select an “f1-micro instance”.
> 5. In the Identity and API access section, give access scope to the Storage API so that you can read and write to your bucket in case you
>      need to do so; the default access scope only allows you to read. Also
>      enable BigQuery API.
> 6. Once you have the instance created and access to the bucket, just create your cron job inside your new instance: In the user account
>      under which the cron job will execute, run crontab -e and edit this
>      file to run the cron job that will execute your baby.sh script.The
>      following [documentation link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-autotasks-cron-configuring.html) should help you with this.
>
> Please note, if you want to view output from your script you may need
>   to [redirect it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309853/getting-output-from-a-cron-job-on-the-terminal?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to your current terminal.

You might need to add more [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) since you are also using Google BigQuery.

Comment: Hi Rubèn, 
Maybe I did not say it clear enough.
I have a Python script that launch some query on BigQuery and save the output on a csv, and that work fine. 
Now I need  to schedule this work to obtain a daily automatic execution.
But on documentation i see that:https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron
I haven't found  how to save files created by script on Google bucket and hot schedule this work. The documentation is 
very dispersive.

Comment: I understand. What is not clear for me is where do you have the Python script. I thought about App Engine but nothing referencing it. So I assumed that you have it on your Cloud Shell (my solution is for this use case). If it is in App Engine you need a cron job to schedule tasks. To save the data on BigQuery, add an [extra operation in the cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) or use the same Python script, [waiting for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) to have the file created.

Comment: i have the scrip in the cloud shell.  
The doc talk about an URL, i have a script and I havent an application.
So how can I do to tell at YAML to execute my script?
This my problem.  

Thanks

Comment: @StefanoG. If you don't have an App Engine application, you don't need the YAML file (my guess is that you are speaking of the `cron.yaml` file). You said in your question that you don't want to build an 'HTML' application, but you would need even the smallest, simple one in App Engine, and modify your script a bit, to run it there. I would just go with @RubenC answer.

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks I these days I can't work on this project. When I will came back at home I will try a bold a mini webapp to drive the script